# Animal Crossing New Leaf: I just got back from the island, where are my tools?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

He said my tools would be given back to me once I get back to the town... but I have nothing! not in the drop-off box, not in the the mail... it's just gone

Comment: Really? Everything you had in your inventory should be right back in your inventory where it started

Comment: Are you referring the the tools in your inventory while you were in the village, or the tools you received from the Gyroid on the island?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you can't bring your tools to the island. So that means you got them from the Gyroid on the island. They aren't your tools, you could only borrow them, (s)he would get them back when you go on a tour, or go back to your town.

Answer (score 1):

There are two probable answers, along with some questions.

Have you checked your inventory? If not, do so.All your items should still be there. 
Next, if you don't know, the Gyroid at the island does not **give** the tools to you. They are only to borrow.This should explain why putting the rental tools into the drop-off box is impossible.

In conclusion, you probably misread the animal's statement.(but, you never really told us who you were speaking with..)